# Using Db2Mon is there a way to distinguish between clients connecting using type 2 and type 4 driver?

Tags: database, db2, database-connection, jdbc

Well, The question explains all,
Using DB2mon tool, Is there a way to tell which client is connecting using which type of connection (type 2 jdbc or type 4 jdbc connection)?
All of the connections are showing as db2jcc process which is the common driver for both type 2 and type 4. 
Also if there is a way to find out whether is connection is UDP or TCP/IP it can be helpful too as the type 2 is UDP based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to find out which type of driver the user is using from db2mon. You can see only the username with which the user loggedin